# Galois group of $f = x^5 - 2x^3 - x^2 + 2$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I've made some progress finding the Galois group of $f = x^5 - 2x^3 - x^2 + 2$ but I am having some difficulties.

I've factorised it over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $f = (x^2 - 2)(x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$ and so I can see the splitting field must be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2), w)$ where $w$ is a primitive cube root of unity. Now I am trying to calculate the degree of this extension. I know that it must be divisible by 2 because it has $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2))$ as a subfield and I know it must be less than 4 (because adjoining the primitive root is a degree 2 extension). Now how do I distinguish between the degree being 2 or 4? I.e. How do we know there is no quadratic polynomial which has a root generating the whole extension?

I also know that $f$ has distinct roots and so it is a subgroup of $S5$ but if the extension is 4, how do I distinguish between the possibilities $V4$ or $C4$?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use the quintic equation? EDIT: never mind I don't know anything about galois

Comment: You distinguish between $V_4$ and $C_4$ by trying to find two distinct elements of order $2$, or one element of order $4$. In this case, look at the two automorphisms of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \omega)$ given by 1) $\omega \mapsto \omega^2$ and 2) $\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt2$.

Comment: The splitting field also has $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$ as a subfield. As this subfield contains non-real numbers it cannot be equal to $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. So the splitting field must have degree $>2$. Also the Galois group must have at least two distinct subgroups of index two accounting for those two subfields. That should help. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it has $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as a subfield. So if the degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ were $2$, it would be *equal* to that subfield (by multiplicativity of degrees and the observation that $[F: L] = 1$ iff $F = L$.) If that were so, in particular, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ would contain a non-trivial third root of unity, which is absurd (proof?)

For calculating the Galois group -- think about where each root of the polynomial can go under an automorphism. Do you have an automorphism of order 4, or not?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm sure this is obvious but, in the first line, why should two degree 2 extensions have to be equal?

Comment: Let $L$ be the splitting field. We know $L$ contains $\sqrt{2}$, so $L \supseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \supseteq \mathbb{Q}$. If $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 2$ then by multiplicativity of degrees either $[L: \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=1$, so those fields are equal to each other, or $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 1$, so those fields are equal to each other.