# Find Galois group of $=^5−2^3−^2+2$

Tags: galois-theory

This question was already answered here: [Galois group of $f = x^5 - 2x^3 - x^2 + 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039715/galois-group-of-f-x5-2x3-x2-2), but I still don't understand some stuff. So this question can be tagged as duplicate.

Sorry about this, but Galois Theory is one of my worst subjects and I am trying to catch on, and I have some questions.

I am ok with the fact that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt(2), \omega)$ is the splitting field. But how I would proceed would be as follows:

$[\Bbb Q(\sqrt(2)):\Bbb Q] = deg(x^2-2) = 2$

$[\Bbb Q(\sqrt(2))(\omega):\Bbb Q] = deg(irr(\omega, \Bbb Q(\sqrt(2)))=deg(x^3+1)$=3

So by Tower Law, [$\Bbb Q(\sqrt(2), \omega)$:$\Bbb Q$] = 6.

So we would be looking for a subgroup of $S_5$ with 6 elements. But that contradicts the possible solutions given by the person who asked the question above. What was my mistake and how do I fix my solution?

Comment: $\omega$ has only degree 2 (since $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$)

Comment: @ahulpke oh, yes, thanks!

Comment: @ahulpke Can you please help me to conclude it? I do not understand the explanations given in the linked question. 

I am looking for an order 4 subgroup of $S_5$, but how do I decide each one?

I would just consider the automorphisms and find some properties of them, but I feel this is not the easiest way to do it...

Comment: It. Reds to be a subgroup that has two orbits of length 2 and one of length 1, same as degree if irreducible factors.